# Group json data in db using a query

Tags: query, group-by, sqlite, json

I have a db whose values are as follows:img Can I call the json value of listing_id(23,27....so on) in properties column(with having row value as "listing") using a single query, I would Really Appreciate the help .[image]

I'm using sqlite .json extension is not available.what I'm trying to do is::group all the rows having listing_id as a single value(23,27...).is there any other way?

Comment: Why are you using JSON data in a database without JSON support? Now you have to restrict the structure of the JSON object, and scrape the value out with [string functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the content of the **properties** column is like in your screenshot, it's easy to remove everything from the content except for the pure number IDs:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(properties, '{"listing_id":', ''), '}', '') AS listing,
       *
FROM   ahoy_events;
```

This will give you the pure numbers from your json column as (new) column *listing*.

```
| listing | id | visit_id | ... | properties        |
|---------------------------------------------------|
| 27      | 57 | 2        | ... | {"listing_id":27} |
| 23      | 58 | 2        | ... | {"listing_id":23} |
```

You can then group by this value.

Was this what you were asking for?